# Can't install apache2 for the first time

Tags: apt, package-management, apache2, dependencies

I am trying to install local server but cannot seem to get past this error where i install apache.

On my terminal i run `sudo apt-get install apache2` and on pressing enter i get this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
apache2 : Depends: apache2-bin (= 2.4.7-1ubuntu4.9) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How do i fix this? I am new to linux that's why.

Comment: Did you do `sudo apt-get update` before installing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have a previous installation of apache in your system. I would first try `apt-get install -f --reinstall apache2`, `-f` to fix unmet dependencies. If that does not solve the problem, I would try `apt-get remove --purge -s apache2`. Purge will remove configuration files and the `-s` will make a 'test uninstall' (not remove anything), so you can check what packages would be removed (they should be only apache2 related packages, if you are unsure, post the output here). Then `apt-get install apache2`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I have tried the first to fix unmet dependencies which gave me the same output. I tried the second option to remove apache files and got this output:  `sudo apt-get remove --purge -s apache2 Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'apache2' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 211 not upgraded.
`

Comment: It is admitting that  apache packages have not been installed as this is the first time i'm doing this.

Comment: try `apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade`, then try again with the `--reinstall` option.

Comment: which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: This has actually worked, sorry i thought i had commented back, network issues. Apparently i am on linux mint 17.3 which i hear is based on ubuntu

Comment: So you jus upgrade the distro? with your first method : `apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade`

Comment: Yes, to discard version problems between your distro and the application you were trying to install. Glad it worked.

Comment: I wouldnt habe thought of that, thanks for the help